# Ajax.net update panels not working on mozilla firefox

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajax.net

Don't know why, but when making the postback for the control to update the ajax updatePanel it actually does the full postback of the page, it works fine on IE however with mozilla it reloads the whole page.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Panel ID="userLogin" Visible=false runat=server>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:Label ID="Label27" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700" 
                    Text="Registered Users"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="style2">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label30" runat="server" Text="New Users" 
                    style="font-weight: 700"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="style7">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label28" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server" Width="160px" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="style2">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label31" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="style7">
                &nbsp;<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox13" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                            ontextchanged="TextBox_TextChanged" TabIndex="3" Width="160px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Classifieds/images/notOk.jpg" 
                            Visible="False" />
                        <asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Classifieds/images/ok.jpg" 
                            Visible="False" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>

         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="registerErrorLabel" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                        &nbsp;<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
                            <ProgressTemplate>
                                <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" 
                                    ImageUrl="~/Classifieds/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
                            </ProgressTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdateProgress>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TextBox13" EventName="TextChanged" />
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TextBox15" EventName="TextChanged" />
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="CheckBox4" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The textbox autopostback is true, and it just check if the user exists or is valid and displays an message on one label inside the update panel.

Here is the code behind of the event that the textbox triggers:

```
protected void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isEmail(TextBox13.Text))
    {
        if (DB2.alreadyRegistered(TextBox13.Text))
        {
            registerErrorLabel.Text = "This email has already been registered,<br/>If you forgot your password please <a href='../../../forgot.aspx' target=blank>click here</a> (will open on a new window)";
            registerErrorLabel.Visible = true;
            Image5.Visible = false;
            Image6.Visible = true;
            TextBox13.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            registerErrorLabel.Visible = true;
            Image5.Visible = true;
            Image6.Visible = false;
            TextBox13.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }     
    }
    else {
        registerErrorLabel.Text = "Please use a valid email";
        Image5.Visible = false;
        Image6.Visible = true;
        TextBox13.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }        
}
```

Comment: umm there is no label within your update panel? are you showing one of those images instead to show whether it is valid or not?

Comment: Also just a recommendation, but you should really have meaningful control IDs because this can become confusing in the code behind and cause some weird behavior through using the wrong control. This might be what is going on now, but it is hard to tell without seeing your code behind.

Comment: sorry about that, There are two columns, 1 for registered users and the other for new users (2 columns on a table) forgot to include the 2nd update panel, one is on the top with an image next to the textbox, the other is on the bottom where the registerErrorLabel is (the label that shows the error if any)

Comment: what version of C# ASP.NET are you using? have you recently upgraded to this version?

Comment: live example here 
http://www.barcelonaconnect.com/classifieds/Add-Classified-Step4.aspx?ccategory=1&sub=2

Comment: why dont you just use one update panel?

Comment: since i started with the ajax thing always 3.5 before we were working with 2.0

Comment: i could group all of them in one, I just didnt want to put all the other textboxes i dont need to do anything with inside one update panel, but shouldnt make too much difference, will try that

Comment: k well anyways just in case check your web.config to make sure that this line is not in it   
<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy"/>   
we had this issue after we moved from 1.1 to 2.0 and it caused a similar issue. Once I removed that line it started to react properly in Firefox

Comment: that is not there in the web.config, added the code behind to the post, i dont think there is anything weird there...  have a look

Comment: I dont see anything that catches my eye; there must be something that we are missing though

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not really working in IE.

You need to set the EnablePartialRendering parameter on your ScriptManager.

Comment: it is set to true, is the default but will try to put it as true in the code as well... lets hope thats it...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the UpdatePanel's UpdateMode to Conditional.

I am seeing the same thing you are - a postback on Chrome and Firefox but not on IE (all latest versions). Could be that IE just plays nicely without specifying the updatemode, where you may have to be more explicit with other browsers.